# Angular 2 error while using templateUrl

Tags: typescript, angular

I am facing an issue when I try to use `templateUrl` in @Component. I am using angular 2, version 2.0.0-beta-0. The error is as follows, please see the link below:

---

[image: error image]
[image: error image]

### class

```
@Component({
selector: 'bootstrap2',
templateUrl: './pages/bootstrap2.html'
```

})

### bootstrap.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
            <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
        </div>

        <label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <nav>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
            Messages <span class="badge">4</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{image0}}" alt="image1">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Case read they must it of cold that. Speaking trifling an to unpacked moderate debating learning. An particular contrasted he excellence favourable on.</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{image1}}" alt="image2">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Case read they must it of cold that. Speaking trifling an to unpacked moderate debating learning. An particular contrasted he excellence favourable on.</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{image2}}" alt="image3">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>Case read they must it of cold that. Speaking trifling an to unpacked moderate debating learning. An particular contrasted he excellence favourable on.</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `/` in `<meta charset="utf8"/>`

Comment: You still get the same error message for the same tag? What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: Try to force-reload in the browser Ctrl+F5

Comment: issue remains the same

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?